# error that wont go away despite numerous changes in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

Good evening,

I have the following error and I have no idea what it means, i have googled and changed a few little bit but its very persistent.  Is anyone able to offer me some help with the matter?

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1452:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/danielwilstrop/Desktop/projects/live-chat-2/server.js:100:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1345:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -48,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 5000
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually caused by a typo on your terminal.
Check if you typed the correct file name in your terminal and also check if the path to your file is correct.

Option 2: check if no other terminals are open in the background. kill all those other terminals, press Ctr+C then run your app again..

Answer (score 0):

There is some other process already using port 5000 so, you are getting this error. To solve this there are two ways

1. Change the server port from `5000` to something else which port is available eg. `5555` in this file `/Users/danielwilstrop/Desktop/projects/live-chat-2/server.js` at line number 100 (as shown in the error)
2. Kill the process that is running on port 5000. Then run the server.js file.

   For Linux or mac `sudo lsof -ti tcp:5000 | sudo xargs kill`

   For windows run cmd with administrator privilages `netstat -ano|findstr "PID :5000"` take the process id from the output and then `taskkill /pid <PROCESS_PID_USING_PORT_5000> /f`